# ImportError at / no module named url, django 1.8.1

Tags: python-2.7, url, django-1.8

I appreciate any help from brilliant minds out there. I am doing Django 1.7 tutorial under the official django documentation and I hit a wall. Here's my problem. I got an ImportError at/, no modules named url when I tried to point the project url (mysite.url) to the application url (polls.url). I'm using Python 2.7.9 and Django 1.8.1.

Here is my polls/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the Polls index page.")
```

Here is my polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Here is my mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.url')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Here is mysite/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

My code looks exactly the same as the  django tutorial BUT I still get the ImportError message. When I commented out 
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.url')) in mysite/urls.py, the server runs fine for 127.0.0.1:8000/ and 127.0.0.1:8000/admin but I can't obviously open polls page because my application urls are not linked to my project urls. Please help open my eyes. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you following the 1.7 tutorial when you're using 1.8?

Comment: This is the latest tutorial they  have posted on the django website. I also looked at the development website for version 1.9 and it still has the same code.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I'm using the exact same website. Way ahead of yah. Tried polls.urls earlier. It gave me a 404. page not found.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `url(r'^polls/', include('polls.url')),` isn't working is because your file is called `polls/urls.py`, not `polls/url.py`.

Comment: Tried using polls.urls multiple times. It gave me a 404: page not found all the time. I tried to add  from polls import urls, but the error is still there.

Comment: Worked for me, thank you! I just changed the name of `polls/urls.py` to `polls/url.py`. They really need to update that tutorial -- not very beginner friendly if you can't get the first page up and running.

Answer (score -1):

In file under

```
mysite/urls.py
```

change line

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.url'))
```

to

```
url(r'polls/', include('polls.urls'))
```